# How to find YouTrack issues with empty description

Tags: youtrack

I have a bunch of issues on YouTrack with empty descriptions. I'd like to filter and find all issues with empty descriptions, so I can quickly add a description to them.
Using `description: ""` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `has: -description` that you need.

Comment: Thanks @Alex.V, that's exactly what I was looking for.
Do you know of a way to enforce description as a required field? It doesn't show up in custom fields.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a custom one. You can only enforce it via a workflow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/youtrack-workflow-reference.html.